# Merging three variables that holds redundant information

Tags: r

After some data wrangling and merging of datasets, I ended up with three variables holding the same information as in the dummy example:

```
cond.x <- c("1","2", "3","4",NA, "4", "1")
cond.y <- c("1", NA, "3",  NA,  "1", "4", NA)
dx <- c("scz", "cont", "siscz", "sicon", "scz", NA,NA)

mydata <-data.frame(cond.x, cond.y, dx)
> mydata
  cond.x cond.y    dx
1      1      1   scz
2      2   <NA>  cont
3      3      3 siscz
4      4   <NA> sicon
5   <NA>      1   scz
6      4      4  <NA>
7      1   <NA>  <NA>
```

So that 1 means scz, 2 means cont, 3 means siscz, 4 means siscon.

- Now how to reduce redundancy creating one variable to hold the information, thus removing the NAs by incorporating data from one of the other two variables?

Comment: Almost there, but this approach is summing two numeric values, instead it should only keep the original value.

Comment: Is `c("scz", "cont", "siscz", "sicon", "scz", "sicon", "scz")` your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `dx` as factor and get their levels in to `level_dx`. Then convert all 3 columns of `mydata` into integer type.

```
mydata$dx <- factor(mydata$dx, levels = c("scz", "cont", "siscz", "sicon"))
level_dx <- levels(mydata$dx)
mydata[, 1:2] <- lapply(mydata[, 1:2], function(x) as.integer(as.character(x)) )
mydata$dx <- as.integer(mydata$dx)
```

Using `fill` function from `tidyr` package, fill the columns with their previous values either up or down direction and convert the `dx` column back to factor variable.

```
library('tidyr')
mydata <- fill( data.frame(t(mydata)), 1:7, .direction = 'up')
mydata <- data.frame( t( fill( mydata, 1:7, .direction = 'down') ) )
mydata$dx <- factor( mydata$dx, levels = sort(unique( mydata$dx )), labels = level_dx)
#    cond.x cond.y    dx
# X1      1      1   scz
# X2      2      2  cont
# X3      3      3 siscz
# X4      4      4 sicon
# X5      1      1   scz
# X6      4      4 sicon
# X7      1      1   scz
```

Data:

```
cond.x <- c("1","2", "3","4",NA, "4", "1")
cond.y <- c("1", NA, "3",  NA,  "1", "4", NA)
dx <- c("scz", "cont", "siscz", "sicon", "scz", NA,NA)

mydata <-data.frame(cond.x, cond.y, dx)
mydata
#   cond.x cond.y    dx
# 1      1      1   scz
# 2      2   <NA>  cont
# 3      3      3 siscz
# 4      4   <NA> sicon
# 5   <NA>      1   scz
# 6      4      4  <NA>
# 7      1   <NA>  <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit shorter, mainly thanks to the `data.table` package:

```
x <- c("1","2", "3","4",NA, "4", "1")
y <- c("1", NA, "3",  NA,  "1", "4", NA)
dx <- c("scz", "cont", "siscz", "sicon", "scz", NA,NA)

mydata <- data.frame(x, y, dx, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(data.table)
# Convert to data.table by reference
setDT(mydata)

# Merge x and y into xy
mydata[, xy := unique(na.omit(x), na.omit(y)), by = dx][]
# Create lookup table
lookup <- mydata[, .(xy = first(xy)), by = dx] %>% na.omit() %>% setnames(c('dx_l', 'xy'))
# Join mydata with lookup using xy
mydata[lookup, dy := dx_l, on = c(xy = 'xy')][]

mydata[, .(dy)]
#       dy
# 1:   scz
# 2:  cont
# 3: siscz
# 4: sicon
# 5:   scz
# 6: sicon
# 7:   scz
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do this using `coalesce` from `tidyr` to create non-NA entries based on both 'cond.x' and 'cond.y', then use the index to update the values in 'dx'

```
library(tidyverse)
mydata %>% 
      mutate(dx = dx[coalesce(cond.x, cond.y)])
#  cond.x cond.y    dx
#1      1      1   scz
#2      2   <NA>  cont
#3      3      3 siscz
#4      4   <NA> sicon
#5   <NA>      1   scz
#6      4      4 sicon
#7      1   <NA>   scz
```